# When I edit my block in Magento 2, Front-end updates but not Block?

Tags: magento2, error, blocks, cms-block

I tried to change my HTML code in my BLOCK. The problem is when I press Save I can see the changes on the live site but my block is still showing the old code.

It also returns "Something went wrong" panel.

Why does site update but Magento 2 doesnt?

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest You to post it on Git If you haven't customize your instance.

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: Yes I did serveral times. No changes. All users that own rights to see the block structure, can only see the old code. I couldn't find an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Magento 2 couldn't read my HTML code. I nested "" tag inside "" tag and that was the case..

So I solved a problem by changing "" to "".

Comment: "div" tag inside "a" tag.